# Combine information from two tables into one using highest of id of each

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

Table A has a keyid column which is unique and an a uid column which identifies an individual. There are multiple rows for each uid.

Table B is the same as Table A but with all of its other columns not present in Table A.

I will create a Table C that contains All of the information of both Table A and Table B

What I would like is a query that takes the highest keyid from Tabla A and the hightest keyid from Table B for each uid and inserts into Table C.

How can I write such a query?

EDIT: Here is some example with the two tables and what I want

```
TABLE A
keyid | uid | name | likes
-----------------------------
  1     15    John   nothing
  2     15    John   something
  3     32    Jane   or other

TABLE B
keyid | uid | fruit | 
-----------------------------
  1     15    oranges
  2     32    banana
  3     32    apple


TABLE C (resulting query)
uid | name | likes     | fruit
-------------------------------
 15   John   something   oranges
 32   Jane   or other    apple
```

Comment: Note that name would not normally be a column in table A, as it creates redundancy

Comment: I think Jane's fruit should be apple (keyid=3) not banana (keyid=2)

Comment: And why is Jane banana, and not apple?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that Jane should have been apple!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) query, selecting the values from each table where the `uid` has the MAX value of `keyid` for that `uid`:

```
CREATE TABLE TableC AS
SELECT a.uid, a.name, a.likes, b.fruit
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM TableA a
      WHERE a.keyid = (SELECT MAX(keyid) FROM TableA a2 WHERE a2.uid = a.uid)) a
JOIN (SELECT * 
      FROM TableB b
      WHERE b.keyid = (SELECT MAX(keyid) FROM TableB b2 WHERE b2.uid = b.uid)) b ON b.uid = a.uid
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
uid     name    likes       fruit
15      John    something   oranges
32      Jane    or other    apple
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c53ab5bffeaffdd1f29aa8594c4407c)

**Update**

To add an auto-increment id column to the table, just specify it as a column in the `CREATE TABLE` part of the query:

```
CREATE TABLE TableC (keyid INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) AS
SELECT a.uid, a.name, a.likes, b.fruit
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM TableA a
      WHERE a.keyid = (SELECT MAX(keyid) FROM TableA a2 WHERE a2.uid = a.uid)) a
JOIN (SELECT * 
      FROM TableB b
      WHERE b.keyid = (SELECT MAX(keyid) FROM TableB b2 WHERE b2.uid = b.uid)) b ON b.uid = a.uid
```

Output:

```
keyid   uid     name    likes       fruit
1       15      John    something   oranges
2       32      Jane    or other    apple
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. I do not want to insert the keyid itself. Just use it to select WHAT to insert. So the query above would work if ONLY the UID is inserted in the new table, alogn with all the other columns

Comment: @aarelovich I've edited my answer based on your comments and edits to your post. btw I think your sample output is wrong, Jane should have apple, not banana in TableC

Comment: You are right. The sample output was incorrect. Thank you for realizing that! I'll test the query as soon as I can!

Comment: I love this solution. Only one problem I want to add incrementing keyid column? Like this:  "keyid              INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " How can I work this into the query

Comment: Never mind! I just inserted the information from TableC to my created table and that did the trick. I got what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @aarelovich See my edit - you can add that column automatically in the generation of TableC

Answer (score 1):

Alternative for MySQL or other db supporting row_number() over()

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TableA(
>    keyid  INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   ,uid    INTEGER  NOT NULL
>   ,name   VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL
>   ,likes  VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TableA(keyid,uid,name,likes) 
> VALUES 
> (1,15,'John','nothing'),
> (2,15,'John','something'),
> (3,32,'Jane','or other');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TableB(
>    keyid  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
>   ,uid    INTEGER  NOT NULL
>   ,fruit  VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TableB(keyid,uid,fruit)
> VALUES 
> (1,15,'oranges'),
> (2,32,'banana'),
> (3,32,'apple');
> ```

> ```
> select
>       a.uid, a.name, a.likes, b.fruit
> from (
>      select *, row_number() over(partition by uid order by keyid DESC) rn
>      from TableA
>      ) a
> inner join (
>      select *, row_number() over(partition by uid order by keyid DESC) rn
>      from TableB
>      ) b on a.uid = b.uid and b.rn = 1
> where a.rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> uid | name | likes     | fruit  
> --: | :--- | :-------- | :------
>  15 | John | something | oranges
>  32 | Jane | or other  | apple
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c0785796d53b6f5ab9cbdadc736364d)*